# Cycle2 - How to nest groups of pager elements within a container

Tags: jquery, nested, pager, jquery-cycle2

I've got the following pager code:

```
<div class="app.js.slideshow" id="gallery_pager">
        <div class="app.js.slide app.js.default">
            <a href="#"><img width="75" alt="Dragonfly #01" src="index.thumb/Dragonfly%20%2301.jpg" name="img" title="Dragonfly #01" height="50" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img width="75" alt="Dragonfly #02" src="index.thumb/Dragonfly%20%2302.jpg" name="img" title="Dragonfly #02" height="50" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img width="75" alt="Dragonfly #03" src="index.thumb/Dragonfly%20%2303.jpg" name="img" title="Dragonfly #03" height="50" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img width="75" alt="Dragonfly #04" src="index.thumb/Dragonfly%20%2304.jpg" name="img" title="Dragonfly #04" height="50" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="app.js.slide">
            <a href="#"><img width="75" alt="Dragonfly #05" src="index.thumb/Dragonfly%20%2305.jpg" name="img" title="Dragonfly #05" height="50" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img width="75" alt="Dragonfly #06" src="index.thumb/Dragonfly%20%2306.jpg" name="img" title="Dragonfly #06" height="50" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img width="75" alt="Dragonfly #07" src="index.thumb/Dragonfly%20%2307.jpg" name="img" title="Dragonfly #07" height="50" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img width="75" alt="Dragonfly #08" src="index.thumb/Dragonfly%20%2308.jpg" name="img" title="Dragonfly #08" height="50" /></a>
        </div>
        ...
</div>
```

By specifying the pager with: "pager":"#gallery_pager > .app\.js\.slide" the individual a img combos in each app.js.slide div become the individual pager elements. However, the index number of the associated slide is reset for every div. So, in the 2nd app.js.slide div, the pager elements link to index 0-3, instead of 4-7.

Worst case I figure I can 'overwrite' the pager function by specifying a goto command for each of the a img tags in question. Before that though I wanted to see if there were any thoughts here.

Thanks!

Comment: since you are probably not letting the plugin build the pager, creating your own paging function is likely going to be easiest

Comment: That's what I ended up doing - wasn't difficult once I got the selector for the images in question.